# Before or Prepend don´t work with images?

Tags: jquery, html, insert, prepend

I need to insert a block of HTML code before a DIV.
I´m facing this with JQuery, using the "before" or "prepend" functions (neither could help). But the problem is that if i insert an image within the new code it gives me a "failed to load URL" error (debugging with Firebug), but the URL is correct (it works at other places of the web).

Here is my code:

```
$("#page").before('<div id="OverPage"><div style="width:400px; margin:0 auto;">Go <img src="~/Images/backInst_20.png" /> Back</div></div>');
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Yep, it works... but removing the "~". Don´t know why... I though it was important for positioning the "Home" folder of the project, and i´m using that way of referencing data all over the web project, but in this case it must be removed. If you know why must it be and the possible consecuences, any additional info would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - you'll need to change id's etc to correspond to your example.

```
   jQuery("<img/>").before("#page").attr({
   src: 'src.gif',
   alt: '',
   height: '60'
});
```